SwiftUI Image display rotates on device
My test app grabs a photo from the device, and then displays it. Simple.
On the simulator, it works great, but on a device, it rotates the image. Sometimes 90 degrees, sometimes 180, sometimes it's not rotated.
Here is the code I am using, minus the button that initiates PhotoPicker:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var theImage: Image = Image(systemName : "chart.bar.doc.horizontal")
    @State private var selectedPhoto: PhotosPickerItem? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            theImage
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhoto, matching: .images) {
                GetPhotoButton()
            }
            .task(id: selectedPhoto, {
                await loadImage(from: selectedPhoto)
                selectedPhoto = nil
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func loadImage(from item: PhotosPickerItem?) async {
        if let theItem = item {
            do {
                let image = try await theItem.loadTransferable(type: Image.self)
                if let image = image {
                    theImage = image
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load image: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}


It sounds like this the Exif data in the images you're testing with. It sounds like your standard viewer interprets these tags and rotates accordingly. However, loadTransferable does not. My guess is that you're seeing an image with no rotation applied and interpretting it as being rotated. You can inspect those details with something like exif tools.

Yes! Thank you @outlaw

Thanks to @outlaw for pointing me in the right direction.
In Apple's documentation for PhotosPickerItem, they state:

Important:
Image only supports PNG file types through its Transferable conformance ...

So it appears that by using loadTransferable(type: Image.self) we are losing important information about the asset, namely its orientation.
So here is a custom Transferable SwiftUI protocol (thanks to Itsuki) to cover formats other than PNG:
struct TransferableImage: Transferable {
    let image: Image
    
    enum TransferError: Error {
        case importFailed
    }
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        DataRepresentation(importedContentType: .image) { data in
            guard let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                throw TransferError.importFailed
            }
            let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            return TransferableImage(image: image)
        }
    }
}

And replace the .task(id: with an .onChange(of:
PhotosPicker(selection: $selectedPhoto, matching: .images) {
    GetPhotoButton()
}
.onChange(of: selectedPhoto) {
    Task {
        if let loaded = try? await selectedPhoto?.loadTransferable(type: TransferableImage.self) {
            theImage = loaded.image
        } else {
            print("Failed to load image")
        }
    }
}

And voila, it works for all images!
